# Withdrawing a chapter proposal: Is anything else required here?

Tags: disreputable-publishers, withdraw, retraction

I have been invited to write a chapter with a publisher, so I wrote a proposal for the chapter using the abstract of a write-up (short primer paper) I had. After sending the proposal, I eventually found out that the publisher’s reputation is controversial.

So I gave it a second thought and wrote an email shortly (within two days) indicating I will like to withdraw my proposal. The next day after sending the email, I got an email from the author service manager stating that the editor has accepted my proposal and 'he has no further suggestions for you at this time. Please continue with the writing process' and that after the review of the chapter, I will get an email of definitive acceptance.

Now, I am about to send the short paper to a magazine. Is there anything else required of me with respect to the first publisher to absolve my work from their publication process.

Comment: Are you writing a chapter in a review volume? You also refer to "send the *paper* to another venue", which makes me wonder what exactly is involved here.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have edited the question. Its a book chapter. However, I wanted to use an 'unsubmitted' manuscript I had.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tell the author service manager again that you are withdrawing your proposal. Use clear language: explicitly say that you're no longer willing to contribute to the book. It sounds like the author service manager didn't realize you're withdrawing and is still expecting a submission from you, and it would be unethical to not correct them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have been communicating with the author service manager and not the editor. I have now included that in the question.

Comment: @Abdulhameed when you wrote the email saying you'd like to withdraw, who did you address it to?

Comment: The "support" email on the publisher's website and the "author service manager". However, since then correspondence has been with the "author service manager".

Comment: @Abdulhameed do I understand correctly that someone (was it the author service manager?) invited you to write, but when you wrote to say you were withdrawing, you did not respond to this person?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes it was the author service manager. Initially, I submitted the abstract of the paper, then after a rethink. I sent an email and forwarded the 'author service manager' indicating that I wanted to withdraw from the commitment to submitting the chapter.

Comment: @Abdulhameed I'd do the same thing then: tell the author service manager (whoever that is) that you are withdrawing with clear language.